# Couchbase createIndex command times out

Tags: couchbase

I have a Couchbase bucket consisting of ~110 mn documents occupying ~58 GB of disk space. The allocated Dynamic RAM Quota of the bucket is 48.8 GB. Index RAM quota for the cluster is ~36 GB. I'm trying to build a secondary index on the bucket using GSI.

The query to create the index runs for ~2 mins and returns an error `GSI CreateIndex() - cause: Request Timeout` , also I'm getting the following warning from the web UI : `Approaching full Indexer RAM warning. Usage of Indexer RAM on node "127.0.0.1" is around 2669%. This is above the threshold of 75%.`

Is there someway I can increase the timeout period for the query? Also, the query only runs for about 2 min before timing out, does that have something to do with the RAM warning, as in an increased hardware requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I created the Query Workbench in the Couchbase 4.5 UI. Are you using the 4.5DP version?

There is indeed a timeout on queries issued from the UI. It should be set for 5 minutes, are you sure about the 2 minutes you are reporting, or could it be 5 minutes? If it's 2 minutes, there could well be a bug.

Please note, however, that index creation continues after this timeout. If you go to the indexes tab, you should see that the index continues to build. So it shouldn't be a problem that the Query Workbench timed out. (I believe we fixed the error message to indicate this in a later version.)

If the indexes tab does not show the index continuing to build, that is very possibly a bug, if so please provide more details about which version you are using.

In general, the entire UI will log you out after 10 minutes of inactivity, so the workbench isn't the right place for long-running queries. The right tool for long-running queries is the 'cbq' command-line tool, which does not have a time limit.

W.r.t. the messages about "Indexer RAM Warning", that is completely unrelated to the timeout in the Query Workbench. You can stop these messages by increasing the amount of RAM given to the indexer in the Settings -> Cluster tab.

Comment: I did use the cbq tool to run the query but ended up getting the same error, the query runs only for 2 minutes. The index tab doesn't show the index being built, in fact I guess the build process doesn't even start because I'm able to re-run the query after it fails without getting an index already exists error, I'm using the 4.5.0-1308 Enterprise Edition (build-1308)

Comment: I checked with the people in charge of the indexer, and they believe that you may have run into a bug. The best way to solve that is to file a ticket at https://issues.couchbase.com (which requires setting up an account, which shouldn't take too long).

Comment: was a ticket created for this im having the same issue in regards to the 2 min timeout coming from cbq